# How to interpret Events from Unique Events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

I'm trying to add some javascript triggered Google Analytics events to a website that is already working with GA.

I've included the following beneath the standard GA script (new ga.js script).

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Extension']);
```

Which seems to be working ok, but the results listed in the Events Overview report (after waiting 24 hours), don't make sense. It states that there have been 1 Total Events and 5 Unique Events (screenshot below).

https://img.skitch.com/20110729-8hufapcq2366rq3cbpuihjgqjd.jpg

Comment: Try seeing it in the classic Google Analytics. I personally have found a few bugs with this new version. If it doesn't work, try using 3 parameters: _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Extension', 'something']); Maybe there's a bug with two...

Answer (score 1):

Unique events are similar events made by a unique visitor.

In your case : 1 visitor who makes 5 time the same event.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you connect Live Chat service to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager then you get all the chat details in your analytics in the Events column.

There you receive Chat, After Hour Survey, Pre - Chat survey and etc, there on the top you'll find TOP events as well Unique events.

Top events refers to all the chats taken place, for example 150 people click on chat 200 times.
Conclusion

200 is the TOP events
150 is Unique Events.

Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unique Events metric is deprecated now. Old days it didn't really showed unique events rather it showed unique dimensions combinations in the report! 
It was really frustrating.

These days we have two metrics: **Unique Events (new)** and Unique Events **(legacy)**

The new one shows REAL unique events count, legacy - report dimension combination.